# getting specified value from SQL table based on current user login to Full name

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have below data in SQL query, and am showing the current user "Domain" logged in I want to show the full name in label based on each user using the Windows form,

I got stuck here, how I can continue to find the value

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
label1.Text = userName.ToUpper();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=AAA;password=******");
con.Open();
string command7 = "SELECT distinct  [fullname] ,[Group]  ,[Domain] FROM [tableA] where fullname is not null and [group] is not null and [Domian] = '"+ label1.Text  + "'";
SqlCommand da7 = new SqlCommand(command7, con);
```

| Full name | Group | Domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex Sam J | A GROUP | test\Alex |
| Jon Pete F | B GROUP | test\Jon |

Comment: You should read about using prepared statements.  Avoid building your query string with string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of full name this way :

```
...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command7, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
labelFullName.Text = da.Tables[0].Rows[0]["fullname"].ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve it like this, thanks

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(da7, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                
                //con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
                while (reader.Read())
                { 
                label21.Text = reader["Technician"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
```